# How to pass parameter to another screen with ionic 1 and angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I created a multi-button screen much like this:

When I click on a button it would have an id and that id I get on its route, I did with list already, but several buttons passing parameter I still can not.

My question is how to pass that button id to another screen.

Avisos.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Avisos">
  <ion-content style="background-color: #FF4500; background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;">
    <div class="row icon-row">
            <div class="col text-center">
              <button class="botao button button-positive" id="1">Icon</button>
              <br>mais informaçoes
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center">
              <button class="botao button button-positive" id="2">Icon</button>
              <br>Avisos
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center ">
              <button class="botao button button-positive" id="3">Icon</button>
              <br>Contato
            </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In that part is where I get the id, How can I get in that part the id of the chosen button? And pass it on side.id?

site.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Site">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="site in sites" href="#/app/conteudoDoSite/{{site.id}}">
        <span ng-bind-html="site.title"></span><span class="badge badge-assertive">{{site.post_count}}</span>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How to pass parameter to another screen with ionic1 and angular1? Can anybody help me? What I am trying to do is that when the user clicks one of these buttons the id is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `ui-sref` instead of `href` in this situation as it allows you to use states instead of paths and also allows you to pass variables to the next view. Here is an example:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="site in sites" href="app.conteudoDoSite({id: site.id})">
```

You also need to make sure that the state you are trying to pass the variable to is configured to receive parameters. Which would look something like this:

```
.state('app.conteudoDoSite', {
  url: '/conteudoDoSite/:id',
  templateUrl: '/* Fill in */',
  controller: '/* Fill in */'
 })
```

I attempted to guess the state by looking at your code, but please make sure that it is correct, before copying the examples.

Comment: I'm trying not to use the site.html. And I tried to do so: <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <a class="botao button button-positive" Id="10" ui-sref="app.conteudoDoSite({siteId: Id})">Icon</a>
                  <br>Notícias do Santuário <br>
                </ion-item> , and it did not work. But when I tried it like this: ui-sref = "app.contaudoDoSite ({siteId: 10})" @Dexter , Would you know to explain why it does not work by putting value in the id?

Comment: Because Angular cannot read HTML attributes out of the box like that, you would have to grab the button element and read out the id if you would want to get id. It would be easier to create an array of id's and `ng-repeat` through the array to create the buttons or to just put it straight into the `ui-sref` yourself.

Comment: I understood. Well first I made this screen with list that was the site.html and worked, but then I needed to do with buttons like this: https://plus.google.com/+JoshuaMorony/posts/Rjhs4RCwek3, but there came a problem like Do this with buttons, which I thought directly of putting an id or a name and then creating a function in ng-click = "button ('1')" ... you would have an example of how to do an array with ids and Call them or would it be using ng-click like I thought of doing? @Dexter

Comment: If you are not using the id for anything else, I would just do it like you initially were thinking of doing it, there is no need to overcomplicate the code if you just need to pass it to the next view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the tips, you helped me a lot your tips helped me think how to do it, thanks. @Dexter

Comment: No worries, glad I could help out. Please mark this answer as the answer to your question so that it is clear that this question has been answered.

Comment: How do I do this? @Dexter

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) link.